# Problema array variable que cambia

Tags: java

Buenos días tengo este código declaro una variable del tipo `int` la cual está dentro de un un `array` de `int`, luego al cambiarle el valor a mi variable e imprimir el `array` me lo imprime con el valor original intenté todo pero no logro o no estoy entendiendo qué hago mal, muchas gracias un saludo.

```
int num = 0;
int y = 0;

int[] myarr = {5, 2, num};


num = 12; 

for(int i=0; i<3; i++){


             System.out.print(myarr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Bueno si quieres cambiar el valor en realidad deberias realizarlo en la posición del array en este caso la posición `2` quedando tu codigo asi:

```
int[] myarr = {5, 2, num};
myarr[2] = 12;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    System.out.print(myarr[i]);
}
```

Si cambias el valor de `num` en realidad no cambias el valor que tiene `myarr`.

Cuando tu declaras tu variable:

```
int num = 10;
```

y la asignas a tu array

```
int[] myarr = {5, 2, num};
```

simplemente le estas asignando un valor a la posición de tu array **(OJO la variable `num` no está ligada a esa posición)** lo que quiere decir que si cambias la variable `num` no necesariamente cambia el valor de la posición de tu array, lo que estas haciendo es simplemente lo siguiente:

```
int[] myarr = {5, 2, 10};
```

Comment: muchas gracias pero por q no funcionaria de la otra manera

Comment: Ok corregire mi respuesta con una descripción del porque no funciona ;)